# How to prevent an infant from taking off her socks?

Tags: infant, clothes

We normally dress our 5-month-old daughter with socks, especially when going out with the stroller.

Then, it takes just few minutes until she starts rubbing her legs and feet until, eventually, the socks go out and she remains barefoot until we notice and put them back. And then the issue repeats over and over, you see the pattern : )

Having tried putting them over the trousers, higher in the ankle, etc. we notice that not much improvement was gained.

We know it is more practical to dress her with some socks-included clothes. But since we do have some trousers that are not like this, we are wondering what would be a good way to make the socks stay at their place longer.

Any ideas other than using glue?

Comment: I was just going to write "glue them", and then I read your last paragraph... Duct tape then? :)

Comment: We gave up, and tried working around that - in the case of the stroller we covered her with a blanket, while in winter we used some kind of bigger, warmer sleeping bag (don't know what to call it in English).
Hope you get better results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had good luck using a product called Sock Ons (http://www.sockons.co.uk/products/sockons/).  They go over the sock and for our daughter at least did a great job keeping the sock in place.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[pre-walking shoes](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/2a/53/2b/2a532bb16f0ca935153032b204ca1787.jpg)** for when you go out doors.

This type of shoes are flexible rather than provide a rigid support and are normally shaped like the child's foot.

Comment: We used Robeez (robeez.com) for both our boys, the elastic band managed to keep them on for the most part, and once the kids did start walking, we started using them as slippers.  Both loved them.

Edit: Having said that, it is a stage, and will pass too...

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize that she's only five months old.. They enjoy playing with things, including their own clothes. They'll take things apart, try and put them back together, move things around, take things off, etc. It's all a part of the psychological process of growing up. She'll grow out of it eventually. If not, I second @Dariusz with the duct tape. Although, Gaff Tape tends to hold much better. ;)

Comment: OP's issue seems more like a result of fidgeting than play (rubbing feet together until the socks come off, vs. pulling them off with her hands) -- but in general, babies absolutely WILL play with their clothes, to the dismay and frustration to parents everywhere :)